# Create an array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following question is no doubt due to my extreme lack of knowledge in javascript.

I have this original code section:

```
var options = {colors: ['#cbb69d', '#603913', '#c69c6e'],};
chart.draw(dataTable,options);
```

The code above works, but I would like to build the colors array before putting it inside 'options' instead of directly declaring the values as on the sample code. So I replaced the above with:

```
var options = new Array();
var colors = new Array();
for($i=0;$i<data['num_contents'];$i++)
    colors.push(data[$i+'_bar_color']);
options.push(colors);

chart.draw(dataTable,options);
```

Assume `data[$i+'_bar_color']` and `data['num_contents']` contain the correct values. The way I build that options array on my code looks not quite right and, sure enough, my code doesn't work. Can anyone provide me with some pointers?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chart.draw` expects the second argument to be an Object, but you are passing an array of array. So, you have do to something like this

```
var options = {};             # Create an object
...
...
options['colors'] = colors;   # Set `colors` property as colors array
```

Also, when you do

```
for ($i = 0; ...)
```

if `$i` is not declared anywhere before that, it will become a global variable. You may not want that. So, don't forget to use `var` keyword, like this

```
for (var $i = 0; ...)
```

Comment: That was it! Many thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can.